# in linux, mono invoke my .so lib return System.EntryPointNotFoundException

Tags: c#, c++, mono

here is my c++ code

```
#include "_app_switcher.h"

std::string c_meth(std::string str_arg) {
    return "prpr";
}
```

my mono code:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestDraft()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c_meth("prpr"));
    }

    [DllImport("/home/roroco/Dropbox/cs/App.Switcher/c/app-switcher/lib/libapp-switcher-t.so")]
    private static extern string c_meth(string strArg);
```

the err output:

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException : c_meth
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Test.Ro.EnvTest.c_meth(string)
  at Test.Ro.EnvTest.TestDraft () [0x00001] in /home/roroco/Dropbox/cs/Ro/TestRo/EnvTest.cs:15 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in <71d8ad678db34313b7f718a414dfcb25>:0
```

I guess it's because my header file is not in /usr/include, so how to specific c++ header file in mono?

Comment: C++'s `std::string` and .NET's `System.String` are not the same type. This isn't going to work even if you fix the immediate error you're seeing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons why your code doesn't work:

1. The function `c_meth` does not exist within your shared library.  The function that does exist is `_Z6c_methNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE`.
2. The C++ class `std::string` and the .NET class `System.String` are different and entirely unrelated.  .NET only knows how to marshal `System.String` to `const char*` and vice versa.

C++ allows function overloading.  That means it needs a way to tell `void foo(int)` apart from `void foo(std::string)`.  To do this, it uses [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) to generate a unique name for each overload.  To disable name mangling for a function you declare it with the `extern "C"` specifier.  This also limits you to C-like interfaces, so you can only pass and return primitive objects and pointers.  No classes or references.  That's fine though, since .NET doesn't know what to do with C++ classes.  You need to accept a raw `const char*` parameter and return a `const char*`:

```
extern "C" const char* c_meth(const char* str_arg) {
    return "prpr";
}
```

---

Returning strings is also problematic.  .NET will try to de-allocate the returned memory after copying the string to the managed heap.  Since the string returned in this case wasn't allocated using the appropriate allocation method, that will fail.  To avoid this you'll need to declare the imported method in C# to return an `IntPtr` and use `Marshal.PtrToString(Ansi|Unicode)` to convert to a `System.String`.

If you do need to return something other than a string constant, you have a couple options:

1. Allocate the memory for the string with the appropriate function.  The function to use is platform-dependent.  See [Mono's documentation](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/#memory-management) for info about which function to use.
2. Allocate the memory in C# and pass the buffer to the unmanaged function using a `System.Text.StringBuilder`:

C++ side:

```
extern "C" void c_meth(const char* str_arg, char* outbuf, int outsize) {
    std::string ret = someFunctionThatReturnsAString(str_arg);
    std::strncpy(outbuf, ret.c_str(), outsize);
}
```

C# side:

```
[Test]
public void TestDraft()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(256)
    c_meth("prpr", sb, 256);
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}

[DllImport("/home/roroco/Dropbox/cs/App.Switcher/c/app-switcher/lib/libapp-switcher-t.so")]
private static extern void c_meth(string strArg, StringBuilder outbuf, int outsize);
```